# Android Timepicker trouble

Tags: android, timepicker

I'm trying to extract the selected time from my `TimePicker` widget, however when I use the `getCurrentHour()` and `getCurrentMinute()` methods it keeps returning the current time rather than the one I have selected.

`

public class TimerClockActivity extends Activity {

```
private Calendar calendar;
private AlarmManager alarmManager;
private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
private TimePicker timePickerOn;
private TimePicker timePickerOff;
private ToggleButton tbCircuitOn;
private ToggleButton tbCircuitOff;
private static AlarmActivity alarmActivity;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer_clock);

calendar = calendar.getInstance();

    timePickerOn = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePickerOn);
    timePickerOff = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePickerOff);
    tbCircuitOn = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbCircuitOn);
    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

    tbCircuitOn.setOnClickListener(new ClickListener());


}


private class ClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId() == R.id.tbCircuitOn) {
            if (tbCircuitOn.isChecked()) {
                // turn alarm on



                timePickerOn.clearFocus();

                Log.d("Hour", String.valueOf(timePickerOn.getCurrentHour()));
                Log.d("Min", String.valueOf(timePickerOn.getCurrentMinute()));



                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePickerOn.getCurrentHour());
                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePickerOn.getCurrentMinute());

                Log.d("The Time", calendar.toString());
                Log.d("Hour", String.valueOf(timePickerOn.getCurrentHour()));
                Log.d("Min", String.valueOf(timePickerOn.getCurrentMinute()));


                Intent myIntent = new Intent(TimerClockActivity.this, AlarmHelper.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(TimerClockActivity.this, 0, myIntent,0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);



            } else {
                calendar.clear();
            }

        }


    }
}
```

}

`

And the having selected a different time to the ones logged logcat shows

`05-06 16:18:49.282  25999-25999/com.me.raspiapp D/﹕ Surface destroy: ANDROID_NATIVE_WINDOW_MAGIC
05-06 16:18:54.142  25999-25999/com.me.raspiapp D/Hour﹕ 16
05-06 16:18:54.142  25999-25999/com.adamgelston.raspiapp D/Min﹕ 18
05-06 16:18:54.142  25999-25999/com.adamgelston.raspiapp D/The Time﹕ java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=?,areFieldsSet=false,lenient=true,zone=Europe/Dublin,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2015,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=19,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=6,DAY_OF_YEAR=126,DAY_OF_WEEK=4,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=1,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=18,SECOND=49,MILLISECOND=103,ZONE_OFFSET=0,DST_OFFSET=3600000]
05-06 16:18:54.142  25999-25999/com.me.raspiapp D/Hour﹕ 16
05-06 16:18:54.142  25999-25999/com.me.raspiapp D/Min﹕ 18`

Any suggestions of a fix?

Comment: Show us your code: how are you setting your `TimePicker` and how are you using it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the time you get back in callback of [OnTimeSetListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener.html)

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
  // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
```

And you can see an example [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html)

Apparently you need to force it to loose focus, then the values are updated

```
// force the timepicker to loose focus and the typed value is available !
timePicker.clearFocus();
// re-read the values, in my case i put them in a Time object.
time.hour   = timePicker.getCurrentHour();
time.minute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
```

Comment: Can I just apply that straight to the widget in my java code. I've tried that like so: `timePickerOn.setOnTimeChangedListener(new TimePicker.OnTimeChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
                onMins = minute;
                onHours =hourOfDay;

                Log.d("ChangeMins", String.valueOf(minute));
            }
        });` and I'm just getting zero back as the value selected

Comment: Nah it's still returning the present time to me

Comment: Then please close this question :)